# magento add base url in xml file

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions

I need to add top links via extension.i accomplish it.but it create wrong url.

```
<default>
    <reference name="root">
        <reference name="top.links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
                <label>Events</label>
                <url>/myextension/index/eventcalender</url>
                <title>Events</title>
                <prepare/>
                <urlParams/>
                <position>10</position>
            </action>
        </reference>
    <default>
```

its adding new top links as events. but problam is it not create correct url

its create **http://127.0.0.1:8080/myextension/index/eventcalender**

instead of **http://127.0.0.1:8080/myextension/index.php/index/eventcalender**
yes I know i can simply solve that  changing

```
<url>/myextension/index/eventcalender</url>   to

 <url>index.php/myextension/index/eventcalender</url>
```

but when i go to 
http://127.0.0.1:8080/myextension/index.php/index/eventcalender

it works correct but i click  top link by staging

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/myextension/index.php/index/eventcalender
```

**index.php/index/eventcalender** part   append again  to link

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/myextension/index.php/index/eventcalender/index.php/index/eventcalender/
```

and give 404 error
so i need to know correct way to give link within xml file above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add these two line like that then your url will  work.

```
 <prepare>true</prepare>
 <urlParams helper="core/url/getHomeUrl" />
```

complete code

```
<default>
   <reference name="root">
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
            <label>Events</label>
            <url>myextension/index/eventcalender</url>
            <title>Events</title>
            <prepare>true</prepare>
            <urlParams helper="core/url/getHomeUrl" />
            <position>10</position>
        </action>
    </reference>
<default>
```

Comment: yes ,but it's only give home url,can you give some tip how to add it with my code.

Comment: added the complete code hope will helpful for you